# Yasnippet prompt when using commands interactively?

Tags: latex, auctex, yasnippet

How can I use `yasnippet` to invoke LaTeX commands interactively?

If I use `auctex` to insert `\usepackage` it starts a minibuffer which lets me select the desired package (including tab completion). Similar for other commands like `includegraphics`. Is it possible to make `yasnippet` to do the same, i.e. help me choosing the package or image etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `yasnippet` to interpret its [`type`](https://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html) as a `command` rather than a `snippet` to interpret the body as lisp code.

The following example allows you to enter LaTeX environments (e.g., as if you had used `C-c C-e`):

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: environment
# key: env
# type: command
# --
(call-interactively #'LaTeX-environment)
```

And here's another option to insert the `\includegraphics` macro:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: includegraphics
# key: ingr
# type: command
# --
(TeX-insert-macro "includegraphics")
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I apply this for example directly to `includegraphics`. I tried this one: `# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: image
# key: img
# type: command
# --
(call-interactively #'TeX-insert-macro "includegraphics")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @student: I've updated the answer for `\includegraphics`.  `TeX-insert-macro` is a function that requires an argument in this case (see its docstring by `C-x f TeX-insert-macro RET`), which is why it's not called with `call-interactively`.  Take a look at the following links to get started with learning a little Emacs lisp if you'd like to know more: [intro manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html), [Bastien Guerry's 15-minute intro](http://bzg.fr/learn-emacs-lisp-in-15-minutes.html), and the [EmacsWiki node](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispIntro).

Comment: thanks, but this doesn't work either. It just inserts the sting `\includegraphics` and does nothing more. Additionally it is very slow.

Comment: @student: it works for me when all the necessary infrastructure is functioning.  First, make sure it works with `M-x TeX-insert-macro` (you need to make sure that [`auctex` recognizes your `\usepackage{graphicx}`](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2006-09/msg00041.html)).  Second, you will need to enter the appropriate parameters in the minibuffer when it prompts.  Third, if will allow you to do completion in a more friendly way if you use something like [`ido-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/InteractivelyDoThings).

Comment: Now it works. I figured out that the problem only occured when trying it in a test file in my home directory. But there also `M-x TeX-insert-macro includgraphics` didn't work. However in other directories it works. Seems a bit strange, but again, thanks a lot!